# How to view logs of running node of ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd

I hosted my ejabberd on the **AWS cloud server** and accessing using **putty**. I start my ejabberd node using the `./ejabberdctl live` command which is working perfectly fine. When I closed my putty session and start again on the next day I can't attach live logs again until I stop that running node and start again. How can I attach live logging of the previously running node?

Answer (score 0):

There are typically two ways to run ejabberd:

A)

`ejabberdctl live` starts a new node and attaches an interactive shell immediately to it. You view the logs immediately in the shell. This is useful for debugging, testing, developing

B)

`ejabberdctl start` starts a new node keeping it running in the background. You can see the log messages in the log files (`/var/log/ejabberd/ejabberd.log` or something like that). This is useful for production servers.

Later, you can run `ejabberdctl debug` to attach an interactive shell to that node. This is useful when you run a production server, and want to perform some administrative task.